# Script runs manually but not via c#

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-server-2012

I wrote a simple console app, the app runs with administrator privilege, the code is based on [this link](https://techhelpguy.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/run-powershell-script-in-a-process-and-monitor-it-c/), the user inputs a `.ps1` (powershell) script **path** and the app execute this script that in this path.

First I tried the app on "Hello World" script and it works fine, but when I try other script, the powershell gives an error.

I have this in the `.ps1` scipt:

```
install-WindowsFeature smtp-server
Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
```

The surprising thing is that if I run this command `install-WindowsFeature smtp-server` manually it works fine.

but I need that the app would do it, and not manually.

Here is the powershell error:

```
install-WindowsFeature : The term 'install-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At c:\users\administrator\desktop\EnableSMTP.ps1:1 char:1
+ install-WindowsFeature smtp-server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (install-WindowsFeature:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Press Enter to exit:
```

Comment: From Windows Explorer (folders) can you find your exe and then click on it ro run as Administrator? if so, does that work? If it does, then you need this application to run with elevated privileges.  This may help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhiln/2007/04/19/using-manifests-to-elevate-an-application-in-vista/

Comment: My app runs as admin as I mentioned in my post

Comment: @Flufy What OS are you running this on? Normally, this would be ran on a server OS and you would need to import `ServerManager` first. You can run this on Win10 with RSAT tools installed.

Comment: I run this on windows server 2012

Comment: @Flufy Before your `Install-WindowsFeature`, put in `Import-Module ServerManager`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me in the past.

In solution explorer, right click on the project-->properties-->Build

Channge platform target from "Any CPU" to x64

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install-WindowsFeature is a cmdlet provided by the ServerManager module. When you run the script manually, you must have this module imported into your session already. When run via the program, the module is not imported and therefore it does not recognize the cmdlet name. Try adding `Import-Module ServerManager` as the first line in your script and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: I may be mistaken on the module name; run `Get-Command Install-WindowsFeature | select module` to see the module name that provides that cmdlet. Then add `Import-Module <thatModuleName>` to your script.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might need a capital "I" ...
Install-WindowsFeature

Comment: Powershell is case insensitive